Moderator Pro Tem Nouncement
Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: Moderators Pro Tempore.
Unlike other sites, this site didn't really have a loud announcement about this. So they've been working mostly in secret quiet all this time. So let us now spend this time to give a round of applause to those who have, over the course of this site's lifetime, stepped up to the plate to take on the role of pro tem moderator, including their newest addition, Growler!




We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

Welcome, @Growler, glad to have you aboard.

@DonKirkby Thanks for the welcoming :) Glad to be part of the team!
